# Toolkit for Charts in Silverlight 4.0

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am using visual studio 2010 and silverlight 4.0 is installed in my system but i am not getting complete toolkit for silverlight. Is there some additional toolkit that i have to install to get all the features?

Please look into it and provide the link if i have to install something extra.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the additional toolkit libraries from here http://silverlight.codeplex.com/.

Enjoy!